# How to build a Simple search page using Spring MVC?

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I have created webapp using Spring MVC and i have done the CRUD operations and now stuck with the search page.

I have already have coded below jsp and the controller.

JSP page body

```html
<div align="center">
        <h1>Search Items</h1>


        <form action="search_1" method="get" modelAttribute="search">
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Category:</td>
            <td>
          <select  type="text" name="category_id">
            <option value="Book">Book</option>
            <option value="Audio Books">Audio Books</option>
            <option value="Videos">Videos</option>
            <option value="Music">Music</option>
          </select>
             </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Publisher ID:</td>
            <td>
          <select  type="text" name="publisher_id">
            <option value="Harper Collins">Harper Collins</option>
            <option value="Penguins">Penguins</option>
            <option value="Franciscan Media">Franciscan Media</option>
            <option value="Orbis">Orbis</option>
          </select>
             </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Price Range:</td>
            <td>Min: <input type="text" name="price_1"/> Max: 
            <input type="text" name="price_2"/></td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="search"></td>
            </tr>

        </table>


        </form>


    </div>
```

Controller

```java
 @RequestMapping(value ="/search_1",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView search_1(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        String category_id = request.getParameter("category_id");
        String publisher_id = request.getParameter("publisher_id");
        int price = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("price"));



        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.setViewName("searchResult");


        return model;
    }
```

Items bean

```java
package com.jwt.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
public class Items implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3465813074586302847L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String ISBN;

    @Column
    private String title;

    @Column
    private String category_id;

    @Column
    private String Author;


    @Column
    private String publisher_id;

    @Column
    private float price;

    @Column
    private int stock;

    @Column
    private int photo_id;



    public int getid() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setid(int id) {
        this.id = id;

    }

    public String getISBN() {
        return ISBN;
    }

    public void setISBN(String ISBN) {
        this.ISBN = ISBN;
    }

    public String gettitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void settitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getcategory_id() {
        return category_id;
    }

    public void setcategory_id( String category_id) {
        this.category_id = category_id;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return Author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String Author) {
        this.Author = Author;
    }

  public String getpublisher_id() {
        return publisher_id;
    }

    public void setpublisher_id(String publisher_id) {
        this.publisher_id = publisher_id;
    }


     public float getprice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setprice(float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

     public int getstock() {
        return stock;
    }

    public void setstock(int stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }


     public int getphoto_id() {
        return photo_id;
    }

    public void setphoto_id(int photo_id) {
        this.photo_id = photo_id;
    }
}
```

The search has to be done as per the search criteria on the JSP page. The results view can be on the same page. It really doesn't matter,

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why are you confused, but let's see if I can help.

In your controller, you have to extract all of the criteria correctly then retrieve the list of items using these criteria from your database. Create a method in a service class that takes these criteria as parameter and returns a list of items. Attached that item in model and display in "searchResult.jsp" page.

Here is a rough controller method that should handle your search

```java
    @RequestMapping(value = "/search_1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView search(HttpServletRequest request) {

        String categoryId = request.getParameter("category_id");
        String publisherId = request.getParameter("publisher_id");
        int minPrice = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("price_1"));
        int maxPrice = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("price_2"));

        List<Item> items = someService.getItems(categoryId, publisherId, minPrice, maxPrice);

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("items", items);
        model.setViewName("searchResult");

        return model;
    }
```

Comment: I tried and still facing an error. Would you be able to please check this   -  https://stackoverflow.com/q/58705364/5002322