# Retrieve data from database using Hibernate with Spring MVC. Error - "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm trying to create a simple webapp with a search Page. I have implemented CRUD part and it's working. I'm new to coding. Having trouble with the search option. Error - "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ISBN""

I need to get list of data as per the search criteria given.

```sql
Database table name = Items 
Columns 
* id - primary key 
* ISBN - String 
* title - String
category_id - String (I changed this from Int to String as I decided to use the book name instead, to make it simple. So this is not an ID its basically the book name so it's kept as a String)
* Author - String 
* publisher_id - String (same logic as category_id)
* price - FLOAT
* stock - INT
* photo_id - INT
```

```
DB DESC
```

[image]

ItemsController.java

```java
@RequestMapping(value ="/search_1")
    public ModelAndView search_1(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        String category_id = request.getParameter("category_id");
        String publisher_id = request.getParameter("publisher_id");

        List<Items> listItems2 = ItemsService.searchitems(category_id,publisher_id);

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.setViewName("searchResult");
        model.addObject("items", listItems2);

        return model;
    }
```

IteamsDAO

```java
package com.jwt.dao;

import java.util.List;

import com.jwt.model.Items;

public interface ItemsDAO {

    public void additems(Items items);

    public List<Items> getAllitems();

    public void deleteitems(Integer itemsId);

    public Items updateitems(Items items);

    public Items getitems(int itemsId);

    public List<Items> searchitems(String category_id, String publsiher_id);
}
```

ItemsDAOImpl

```java
package com.jwt.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.jwt.model.Items;

@Repository ("ItemsDAO")
public class ItemsDAOImpl implements ItemsDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void additems(Items items) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(items);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Items> getAllitems() {

        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Items")
                .list();
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteitems(Integer itemsId) {
        Items items = (Items) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(
                Items.class, itemsId);
        if (null != items) {
            this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(items);
        }

    }

    public Items getitems(int itemsId) {
        return (Items) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(
                Items.class, itemsId);
    }

    @Override
    public Items updateitems(Items items) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(items);
        return items;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Items> searchitems(String category_id, String publsiher_id) {

        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Items E where E.category_id = category_id AND E.publisher_id=publisher_id")
                .list();

    }

}
```

Items.java

```java
package com.jwt.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
public class Items implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3465813074586302847L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String ISBN;

    @Column
    private String title;

    @Column
    private String category_id;

    @Column
    private String Author;


    @Column
    private String publisher_id;

    @Column
    private float price;

    @Column
    private int stock;

    @Column
    private int photo_id;



    public int getid() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setid(int id) {
        this.id = id;

    }

    public String getISBN() {
        return ISBN;
    }

    public void setISBN(String ISBN) {
        this.ISBN = ISBN;
    }

    public String gettitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void settitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getcategory_id() {
        return category_id;
    }

    public void setcategory_id( String category_id) {
        this.category_id = category_id;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return Author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String Author) {
        this.Author = Author;
    }

  public String getpublisher_id() {
        return publisher_id;
    }

    public void setpublisher_id(String publisher_id) {
        this.publisher_id = publisher_id;
    }


     public float getprice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setprice(float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

     public int getstock() {
        return stock;
    }

    public void setstock(int stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }


     public int getphoto_id() {
        return photo_id;
    }

    public void setphoto_id(int photo_id) {
        this.photo_id = photo_id;
    }
}
```

ItemsService.java

```java
package com.jwt.service;

import java.util.List;

import com.jwt.model.Items;

public interface ItemsService {

    public void additems(Items items);

    public List<Items> getAllitems();

    public void deleteitems(Integer itemsId);

    public Items updateitems(Items items);

    public Items getitems(int itemsId);

    public List<Items> searchitems(String category_id, String publsiher_id);


}
```

ItemsServiceImpl.java

```java
package com.jwt.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.jwt.dao.ItemsDAO;
import com.jwt.model.Items;

@Service
@Transactional
public class ItemsServiceImpl implements ItemsService {

    @Autowired
    private ItemsDAO itemsDAO;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void additems(Items items) {
        itemsDAO.additems(items);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Items> getAllitems() {
        return itemsDAO.getAllitems();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteitems(Integer itemsId) {
        itemsDAO.deleteitems(itemsId);
    }

    public Items getitems(int itemsid) {
        return itemsDAO.getitems(itemsid);
    }

    public Items updateitems(Items items) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return itemsDAO.updateitems(items);
    }

    public void setitemsDAO(ItemsDAO itemsDAO) {
        this.itemsDAO = itemsDAO;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Items> searchitems(String category_id, String publsiher_id) {
        return itemsDAO.searchitems(category_id, publsiher_id);   
        }


}
```

Input search JSP page

search_1.jsp

```html
<div align="center">
        <h1>Search Items</h1>


        <form action="search_1" method="get" modelAttribute="items">
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Category:</td>
            <td>
          <select  type="text" name="category_id">
            <option value="Book">Book</option>
            <option value="Audio Books">Audio Books</option>
            <option value="Videos">Videos</option>
            <option value="Music">Music</option>
          </select>
             </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Publisher ID:</td>
            <td>
          <select  type="text" name="publisher_id">
            <option value="Harper Collins">Harper Collins</option>
            <option value="Penguins">Penguins</option>
            <option value="Franciscan Media">Franciscan Media</option>
            <option value="Orbis">Orbis</option>
          </select>
             </td>
        </tr>



        <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="search"></td>
            </tr>

        </table>


        </form>


    </div>
```

search results will populate here

searchResult.jsp

```html
      <div align="center">
        <h1>Book shop Inventory</h1>

        <table>

            <th>ISBN</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Publisher</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Stock</th>
            <th>Photo</th>


            <c:forEach var="items" items="${listItems2}">
                <tr>


                    <td>${items.ISBN}</td>
                    <td>${items.title}</td>
                    <td>${items.category_id}</td>
                    <td>${items.author}</td>
                    <td>${items.publisher_id}</td>
                    <td>${items.price}</td>
                    <td>${items.stock}</td>
                    <td>${items.photo_id}</td>


                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
         </br>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Search Again" onclick="window.location.href='http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCHibernateCRUD_1/search'">
    </div>
```

Full error message

```
root cause

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ISBN"
    java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    javax.el.ListELResolver.coerce(ListELResolver.java:163)
    javax.el.ListELResolver.getValue(ListELResolver.java:51)
    org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:104)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:1026)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.searchResult_jsp._jspService(searchResult_jsp.java:131)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

Comment: are you using mysql If yes could you please share DESC YOUR table name

Comment: Drop your table and re create it. May be your column containing both `string` and `int` values in single column

Comment: @Vipul I just added it to the question now.

Comment: @Sudhir Ojha The data aren't mixed. The column's data as per the defined data type only. Anyway I'll drop and create another to check

Comment: @NalakaSapumal which database are you using still not clear ;

Also could you please execute this DESC table name in your terminal console

Comment: @Vipul I'm using MySQL and created my DB using MySQL workbench. I added a snap of the table DESC into the question. Appreciate your support.

Comment: @NalakaSapumal
 as yoour desc output says ISBN as NON null and you are passing blank value which is considered as null. Try to save something in ISBN.
you can also try logging before save method.

Comment: @Vipul I'm only trying the search function here. I just want to fetch the data from the database as per the search criteria. So just wondering would it matter if ISBN is null since I'm not passing any values? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simple syntax issue at the end. @saifulislamplabon Answer fixed my Hibernate part and Error -" java.lang.NumberFormatException For input string: "ISBN" was causing because my JSP page had an error with `<c:forEach` tag. It was caused by the white space between `<% @page`. I corrected it to `<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>` and everything works fine now. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the criteria as parameters to get result in `ItemsDAOImpl`

```java
public List<Items> searchitems(String category_id, String publsiher_id) {

        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Items E where E.category_id = :category_id AND E.publisher_id= :publisher_id")
                .setParameter("category_id", category_id)
                .setParameter("publisher_id", publsiher_id)
                .list();

    }
```

In your `searchResult.jsp` you are iterating over `listItems2` but you added is attribute as `items` in your controller.

Change

```
 <c:forEach var="items" items="${listItems2}">
```

to

```
 <c:forEach var="items" items="${items}">
```

On an other note, please name the entities properly. Entity name should be `Item` and collection name should `Items`. But do that later, first try to fix the current problem.

Comment: It fixed some issues but I'm still getting the same error. However, I can see from IDE hibernate is working with the given query. 

Error -" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ISBN" "