# Getting error - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

This is an extension of another issue ([Retrieve data from database using Hibernate with Spring MVC. Error - "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58705364/retrieve-data-from-database-using-hibernate-with-spring-mvc-error-java-lang)).

I just changed my search criteria to add price values. I'm not sure if I have added the HQL correctly. Please assist to check below code.

```java
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Items> searchitems(String category_id, String publisher_id,float price_1, float price_2) {

        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Items items where items.category_id = :category_id AND items.publisher_id= :publisher_id AND items.price< :price_1 AND items.price> :price_2")
                .setParameter("category_id",category_id)
                .setParameter("publisher_id",publisher_id)
                .setParameter("price_1", price_1)
                .setParameter("price_2", price_2)
                .list();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My controller was converting price input as an Int where it should have been a float. After changing it to float issue resolved.